# How do I reference sprites added in gamescene.sks in code like I would an IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I can make sprites fully in code, but I can't figure out how to place a sprite in gamescene.sks, then reference it in gamescene.swift to make changes to it like I would an IBOutlet.

I was able to do this with a sprite named "beam" in gamescene.sks:

```
 let beam = childNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode
```

in

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
    let beam = childNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode

    if let body = physicsWorld.body(at: touchLocation) {
        if body.node!.name == "leftTap" {

                beam.rotateBy(CGFloat(10))
                print("Began touch on Left")

        }else if body.node!.name == "rightTap"{

                beam.rotateBy(CGFloat(-10))
                print("Began touch on right")

        }
    }
}

}
```

And it works, i initially placed the sprite in gamescene.sks and referenced it here. But when I place this line:

```
let beam = childNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Anywhere else in gamescene.swift, it throws than error saying I need to change it to this:

```
let beam = SKSpriteNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode
```

then when I change it I get an error saying: "argument labels '(withName:)'do not match any available overloads"

I'm new to sprite kit and would appreciate some advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you try putting the sprite in a local variable and referencing that local variable in code

```
private var someObject = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    if let someObjectNode = self.childNode(withName: "//someObject") as? SKSpriteNode {
        someObject = someObjectNode
        someObject.zPosition = 50
    }
}
```

And then in touches began just reference someObject instead of looking for the object in the gameScene every time.

Comment: Thank you! is the "//someObject" supposed to be the name I gave the sprite in gamescene.sks? What are the two // for?

Comment: yes that is whatever you name it in the SKS scene file. the // is to traverse through all children and find one that matches this name regardless of if it is nested within another object

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it as a lazy variable,  `self` does not exist yet, which is why your compiler is throwing errors

`lazy var beam = self.childNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode`

If this doesn't work, then try:

`lazy var beam = { return self.childNode(withName: "beam") as! SKSpriteNode}()`

What `lazy` does is allow for your variable to be loaded at the moment it is needed, not during init.

The reason why you would do this approach instead of doing it as a local variable is for optimization.  Searching through the scene everytime is going to be time consuming, where doing the search only once obviously is not.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Comment: I tried both methods you suggested and got a "gameScene has no member childNode error"

Comment: Then you have a problem with gamescene not being skscene